# How do I compile Doom3?

Tags: xcode

Has anyone compiled doom3, released here:
https://github.com/TTimo/doom3.gpl ?

I have never done something like that before (compile c++/xcode project) and a how-to would be more than welcome.

Also how do I know if it can run in my macbook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you compile the engine? It is *not* the full game, so you wouldn't be able to play after compilation.

Anyway, if you're still interested, there's a thread on [Hacker News](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3267701) speaking about it, they also mention how to compile the project if you don't have Xcode 3.2

Edit: for what is worth, [here](http://fabiensanglard.net/doom3_macosx/index.php) the instructions for Xcode 4.

Comment: I think you've spotted one of my biggest goofs ever. Got over excited and thought it was the actual game...

Comment: @dim `This source release does not contain any game data, the game data is still
covered by the original EULA and must be obeyed as usual.` It's in the README.txt